# Checking if file exists

Tags: php

I have a piece of code that checks whether an image exists in the file system and if so, displays it.

```
if (file_exists(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . $user_image))) {
    echo '<img src="'.$user_image.'" />';
} 
else {
    echo "no image set";    
}
```

If I echo `$user_image` out, copy and paste the link into the browser, the image is there.
However, here, the 'no image set' is always being reached.

The `$user_image` contents are `http://localhost:8888/mvc/images/users/1.jpg`

Some of these functions not needed?

Any ideas?
Broken code or a better way of doing it (that works!)?

Comment: to begin with, why not try printing out the contents of `realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . $user_image))` to see where the file_exists is actually looking...

Comment: When you say print it out, you mean echo or print_r?

Comment: Aren't you missing a `/` between `dirname(__FILE__)` and `$user_image`?

Comment: as an aside, consider what will happen if the contents of `$user_image` is an empty string... file_exists will be looking at the parent directory and will return true. `is_file` is probably a more appropriate function in this case.

Comment: The contents of $user_image is http://localhost:8888/mvc/images/users/1.jpg, that must change what I need here?

Comment: var_dump would probably be more useful to you than either echo, or print_r in this case, but any would work.
However, the fact that you have 'localhost::8888' in the image path is worrying. That is the Host Name of the local server and shouldn't be being used to locate files on the file system.

Comment: It's a false bool but it's definitely there as I've pasted the link into the browser. I think I'm confusing the URL with the file system as you say about the localhost. I have a URL constant that I preceded images/users/1.jpg with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beside @hek2mgl answer which i think is correct, i also think you should switch to `is_file()` instead of `file_exists()`. 
Also, you can go a bit further like:

```
if(is_file(dirname(__FILE__). '/' . $user_image) && false !== @getimagesize(dirname(__FILE__) . '/'. $user_image)) {
   // image is fine
} else {
   // it isn't
}
```

L.E:1
Oh great, now you are telling us what $user_image contains? Couldn't you do it from the start, could you?
So you will have to:

```
$userImagePath = parse_url($user_image, PHP_URL_PATH);
$fullPath = dirname(__FILE__) . ' / ' . $userImagePath;
if($userImagePath && is_file($fullPath) && false !== @getimagesize($fullPath)) {
   // is valid
}else {
   // it isn't
}
```

L.E: 2
Also, storing the entire url is not a good practice, what happens when you switch domain names? Try to store only the relative path, like `/blah/images/image.png` instead of `http://locathost/blah/images/image.png`

Comment: My apologies, I didn't add it as I forgot that I had added the root onto it since I last used the code. The example you used in the second code box doesn't work. The file is 100% in the place I linked to!

Comment: I have a URL constant that holds everything before images/users/1.jpg. I can remove this? How would that change things?

Comment: what happens if you just: `var_dump(is_file(dirname(__FILE__).'/mvc/images/users/1.jpg'));` what is the output?the php file from where you run this code is inside mvc directory, on the same level as the images folder? If so, remove the `mvc` from the file location, it is included in `dirname(__FILE__);`

Comment: That's what `parse_url($user_image, PHP_URL_PATH);` is already doing. Are you sure that the image is in that path relative to that PHP file?

From the URL you've provided it looks like it should be relative to your site/application's root directory.

Comment: It's returns a false boolean. The code is inside a folder called users/profile that sites in the directory that images/users is in. The users and images folders are on the same level.

Comment: so you have /mvc/users/profile/index.php ? and /mvc/images/users/ ?  if that's the case, then: `var_dump(is_file(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../images/users/1.jpg'));`

Comment: /mvc/users/profile.php, so I'll just remove one of those ../ out there.

Comment: I won't remove one of those because it's /mvc/views/users/profile.php so it's the correct directory link by you. That returns a true boolean.

Comment: if returns true, that means you got on the right `path`. So, you really need to learn how this path thing works before you do something else. also, so me a favor, what does: `var_dump(is_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .  parse_url($user_image, PHP_URL_PATH)))` gives? If it's still true, then you got your question answer :)

Comment: Yep still true, cheers bud. I'll learn from this, I have to put some more images in place around the site so I'll need to change the paths again. I've always had the code at the same level so it's worked but I'm doing things with an MVC folder layout and as a result, levels are changing! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please make sure you understand how MVC works and also read about absolute and relative paths. One more thing that might help you, is to define some constants in your index.php file for example, then use those constants everywhere in your code when you want to reference a path.

Comment: I have already one constant to get to full URL, back to localhost. I must get to grips with absolute and relative paths and I'll use constants for differing path levels.

Answer (score 2):

You missed the directory separator `/` between path and filename. Add it:

```
if (file_exists(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . $user_image))) {
```

Note that [`dirname()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) will return the directory **without** a `/` at the end.

Comment: Tried this, no change. I've edited the question with what my $user_image contains. That may change what I need here? This is an old piece of code and I think my directories are behaving differently.